# Geometry Transformation, Matrix operations

Tags: matrix, geometry, game-engine, computational-geometry, game-physics

I have an existing transformation matrix, Assume [4*4]. Now I have another transformation matrix[4*4]. I would like to accumulate the effect of both. But Since I am not good in matrix operations. How to accumulate the effects for

1. Rotation
2. Translation
3. Scaling

Comment: The nice thing about transformation matrices is that you can just multiply them to accumulate the effect. This is often referred to as "composing". However, order will matter, so you need to keep that in mind. What language are you using? Many will have a way to multiply matrices.

Comment: I accept it. In my case I am doing rotation, scaling and translation without an order (actually for adjusting a 3D model). I need a net results only. What I need is, the net result, How it is possible?

Comment: Well, you have to specify an order. If you translate then rotate, you will get a different answer than if you had rotated then translated :). Do you have three separate matrices - one for rotation, one translation, and one scale?

Comment: I accumulate all transformation into one 4*4 matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  aganders3 commented,  to accumulate the effect, matrices should be multiplied, order matters [If you translate then rotate, you will get a different answer than if you had rotated then translated]

Refer this link : 140.129.20.249/~jmchen/cg/docs/rendering%20pipeline/rendering/matrix_manip.html